# How to display the input value?

Tags: c++, arrays

When the is 200 the program doesn't read it. How to solve this problem? The program needs to print the ranges and the numbers but if the user input 200 it doesn't work. For example the user input numbers 180, 190, 200. The expected out put is 3 but the output is only 2. See the image attached for more details.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more about what your program is doing, what is your input, what is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: `200 / 25` is 8, which is out of range for `results` (with a valid index range of 0 to 7)

Comment: @BoP what should I do next to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the statement:

```
results[scores[i] / 25]++;
```

You should **check** that the expression `scores[i] / 25` is within the size of the vector `results` otherwise this is **undefined behavior**.

In your case, for the value `200` the expression `scores[i] / 25` comes out to be 8. But since the size of the `results` vector is `7`, your going out of bounds and this leads to **undefined behavior**.

You can use `std::vector.at()` member function to **prevent** this from happening. So you can modify that statement to look like:

```
results.at(scores[i] / 25)++;//this will throw if you go out of bounds
```

This has the advantage that your program will now **not have** undefined behavior.

You can also add a check to see if `scores[i] / 25` is greater than or equal to the size of the `results` vector, then you can ask the user again for input.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use fixed-sized vectors, make sure the largest input score isn't too large. In my example, you can take the min of the input value and the largest allowed number. If you have N=25 buckets, and the largest number you accept is 200, then 200/25=8 is the largest bucket index you would like to reach, meaning you need a bucket of size 9.

````cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double largest_allowed_score = 200;  // if a score is larger than this, use this value isntead of the score
size_t N = 25;  // number of entries to read in, results has the size of largest_allowed_score/N + 1

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double largest_allowed_score = 200;  // if a score is larger than this, use this value isntead of the score
size_t N = 25;  // number of entries to read in, results has the size of largest_allowed_score/N + 1

int main()
{
    vector<double> scores(N);

    cout << "Enter Score: \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        double val;
        cin >> val;
        val = min(val, largest_allowed_score);
        scores[i] = val;
    }
    size_t res_size = static_cast<int>(largest_allowed_score) / N + 1;  // the number of buckets, result size, or resolution 
    vector<double> results(res_size);

    // count the occurances in each bucket
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        results[static_cast<int>(scores[i]) / N]++;

    // print the buckets
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res_size; i++)
        cout << i * N << " - " << (i + 1) * N << ": " << results[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
````